# Python 3.4 - Library for 2D graphics

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics, drawing

As title says, I'm looking for a 2D graphic library, where I can create a window, and then draw lines and basic shapes on it. I was searching around for a similar topics, and I've found something about GTK & Cairo. I have some experience with drawing in Java 2D Graphics library, so I would like to be able to create some small games like Space Invaders, Snake...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for a slightly more static version of GUI which is less about moving visuals, you should check out [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) which comes as python's default GUI

On the other hand, if you want to make "small games like Space Invaders, Snake...", the [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) module would provide you with a great set of tools to easily create these games. I suggest you check them both out and see which one suits your needs better.

Good Luck

Comment: Just one more question, is it possible to install an older PyGTK & Cairo on Python 3.4v Win version? Because, I have found a lot of tutorials on it so...

Comment: @user3385945, You might face some problems and it would be best to check out the respective site's advice on forward compatibility.